# Upload multiple images angular - mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipartform-data, mean-stack

I'm currently working with a mean stack, and I want to be able to choose multiple pictures in my angular project.

Each picture should then be loaded into some sort of thumbnail(with a remove button for each picture :o)), and first when I press the "save" button the pictures should be sent to the Express-Node backend - with the _id of the object they're belonging to.

I have tried to google it, but it seems that people want the pictures to be uploaded right after they're selected - this is not what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas for a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had built a small app that does this, it uploads multiple files 
https://github.com/gs-akhan/node-fileupload-example

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I'm searching for. I just need the frontend/angular-magic - kinda. like ng-flow .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ng-flow: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow - It works like a charm!